# Using external function in node js route

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, express, ejs

I'm trying to use an external function in my route which applies changes to my ejs view.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
Project
    functions
        Evening.js
        Morning.js
        MyFunc.js
    routes
        about.js
        index.js
        users.js
    views
        about.ejs
        index.ejs
    app.js
```

Additionally I have my MyFunc.js:

```
var morning = require('./Morning');
var evening = require('./Evening');

module.exports = {
  GetMorningMessage: function () { console.log(morning); },
  GetEveningMessage: function () { console.log(evening); }
};
```

I understand that I can use `app.get()` in my app.js to set all of the needed parameters to apply certain changes to my views, but I wonder if I can use `app.use()` in app.js and call the external functions in my routes like `router.get()`?

For example like this **(in index.js)**:

```
var morning = welcome.GetMorningMessage();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'The index page!',
    h1: 'The h1',
    username: username,
    currentDate: currentDate,
    MyVar: morning
  });
});
```

Comment: `var morning = require('./Morning');` What does your `morning` variable contain?

Comment: `GetMorningMessage`, returns nothing, it just logs out morning..